# What are the ellipses (...) for in managing an event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ellipsis

I'm a beginner in react, and I'm following a tutorial for display objects returned by a REST api.
In `handleChangeTitle` method I get the value written in text box, and I update the state of component with new activeItem:

```
handleChangeTitle(e){
    //ogni volta che cambia qualcosa nella casella di testo, viene chiamata questa funzione
    var name = e.target.name
    var value = e.target.value 
    console.log('Name:', name)
    console.log('Value:', value)
    this.setState({
      activeItem:{
        ...this.state.activeItem,
        title:value
      }
    })
  }
```

What are the ellipsis for before referring to `this.state.activeItem`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: It is called the spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax, This is used to create a shallow copy of the object instead of modifying the reference of the current state.

Comment: It is a spread syntax, link shared above by  
epascarello

Comment: why is it tagged as py?

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Python. This does not have anything to do with ellipsis in Numpy or Python. `...` means something entirely different in JavaScript than it does in Python.

Comment: also whats the mean of `casella di testo`?

Comment: @rv.kvetch It's Italian, I was explaining to myself what happens in the function. Casella di testo means text box.

Comment: @Jesper I tagged python because I confused it with Ellipsis in Python, which is the first result I obtained searching it on web. I never seen it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the *spread syntax*. It is a quick syntax to copy one object to another.

```
let obj1 = { a: 1 }
let obj2 = { ...obj1, b:2}
console.log(obj2)
```

Following code will print: `{a:1,b:2}`

Meaning content of obj1 was copied in obj2.

You can override values in new object as well, for eg:

```
let obj3 = {...obj2, b:3, c:2}
console.log(obj3)
```

This will print: `{a:1,b:3,c:2}`, the value of *b* was overridden.

You can follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for in-depth explanation.